# DemoAPI (JSONs) to recyclerView using retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Trying to take the JSONs from the API using jsonlint and apply to the recyclerview without success, the application crashes without any warning in the debugger.

**Layouts**:

**dt_product**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/records_BTN_back"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.TextButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:iconSize="45dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/back"
            app:iconTint="@null"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="32dp">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImage2"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/paris"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />



        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/details"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_rv_prodcts**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvProducts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**rv_product_item**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="216dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/paris"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#595959"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="paris"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**myapplication-adaptors,networking**:
**ActivityRvProducts**:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.myapplication.adaptors.RVRetrofitAdaptor;
import com.example.myapplication.networking.ProductResult;
import com.example.myapplication.networking.RetrofitClient;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ActivityRvProducts extends AppCompatActivity implements RVRetrofitAdaptor.OnItemClickListener {
    RecyclerView rvProducts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rv_prodcts);
        rvProducts = findViewById(R.id.rvProducts);

        getProducts();
    }

    private void getProducts() {
        Call<List<ProductResult>> apiCall = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApis().getProducts();
        apiCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductResult>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductResult>> call, Response<List<ProductResult>> response) {
                List<ProductResult> productResult = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(ActivityRvProducts.this, "Got Products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setAdapter(productResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductResult>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityRvProducts.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAdapter(List<ProductResult> productResults) {
        rvProducts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RVRetrofitAdaptor rvRetrofitAdaptor = new RVRetrofitAdaptor(this, productResults);
        rvRetrofitAdaptor.setOnItemClickListener(this); // Set the click listener
        rvProducts.setAdapter(rvRetrofitAdaptor);
    }

    // Implementing onItemClick method of the OnItemClickListener interface
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(String productId) {
        // Handle item click here, start DetailActivity with necessary data
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("productId", productId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity**:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.myapplication.networking.RetrofitClient;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dt_product);

        // Retrieve data passed from previous activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String productId = extras.getString("productId");

            // Display the data as needed in your detail layout
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
            TextView descriptionTextView = findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);

            // Use RetrofitClient to fetch product details
            RetrofitClient.getInstance().fetchProductDetails(productId, new RetrofitClient.OnProductDetailsFetchedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProductDetailsFetched(String[] productDetails) {
                    // If product details are fetched successfully
                    String description = productDetails[0];
                    String imageUrl = productDetails[1];

                    // Load image using Glide
                    Glide.with(DetailActivity.this).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.paris).into(imageView);

                    descriptionTextView.setText(description);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProductDetailsFetchFailed() {
                    // Handle case when fetching fails
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Failed to load product details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Handle case when no data is passed
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Find and set click listener for the back button
        findViewById(R.id.records_BTN_back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish the current activity to go back to the previous one
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the start button
        ImageButton startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

        // Set OnClickListener for the start button
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start ActivityRvProducts when the button is clicked
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityRvProducts.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**adaptors-RVRetrofitAdaptor**:

```
package com.example.myapplication.adaptors;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.networking.ProductResult;
import java.util.List;

public class RVRetrofitAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVRetrofitAdaptor.RVHolderRetrofit> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ProductResult> mProductResults;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public RVRetrofitAdaptor(Context context, List<ProductResult> productResults) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mProductResults = productResults;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RVHolderRetrofit onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_product_item, parent, false);
        return new RVHolderRetrofit(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVHolderRetrofit holder, int position) {
        ProductResult product = mProductResults.get(position);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(product.getProductImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.paris)
                .error(R.drawable.paris)
                .into(holder.ivImage);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(product.getId());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mProductResults.size();
    }

    public static class RVHolderRetrofit extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView ivImage;

        public RVHolderRetrofit(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        }
    }

    // Interface for item click
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String productId);
    }
}
```

**networking**:
**APIs**:

```
package com.example.myapplication.networking;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.Call;

public interface APIs {
    String BASE_URL = "https://fakestoreapi.com/";
    @GET("products")
    Call<List<ProductResult>> getProducts();
}
```

**ProductResult**:

```
package com.example.myapplication.networking;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class ProductResult {
  @SerializedName("id")
  String id;

  @SerializedName("title")
  String title;

  @SerializedName("description")
  String description;

  @SerializedName("image")
  String productImage;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getProductImage() {
    return productImage;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

**RetrofitClient**:

```
package com.example.myapplication.networking;

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static RetrofitClient instance = null;
    private final APIs apis;

    private RetrofitClient(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIs.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        apis = retrofit.create(APIs.class);
    }
    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new RetrofitClient();
        return instance;
    }
    public APIs getApis(){
        return apis;
    }
    public void fetchProductDetails(String productId, final OnProductDetailsFetchedListener listener) {
        Call<List<ProductResult>> call = apis.getProducts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductResult>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductResult>> call, Response<List<ProductResult>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<ProductResult> productList = response.body();
                    if (productList != null && !productList.isEmpty()) {
                        for (ProductResult product : productList) {
                            if (product.getId().equals(productId)) {
                                String description = product.getDescription();
                                String imageUrl = product.getProductImage();
                                String[] productDetails = new String[]{description, imageUrl};
                                listener.onProductDetailsFetched(productDetails);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If product details are not found or response is not successful
                listener.onProductDetailsFetchFailed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductResult>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Handle failure case
                listener.onProductDetailsFetchFailed();
            }
        });
    }
    public interface OnProductDetailsFetchedListener {
        void onProductDetailsFetched(String[] productDetails);

        void onProductDetailsFetchFailed();
    }
}
```